# Why does installing MSVC redistributables require administrator privileges?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, c++-cli, software-distribution, vcredist

This is a very frustrating part of deploying applications on Windows. We have two choices: redistribute the required DLLs in our application directory, or use merge modules and administrator permission to install it system-wide (if it's not already installed). It seems to me that Microsoft could simply digitally sign their DLLs and allow installation of those DLLs into WinSxS without elevation. The same could be done for .NET.

The static runtime and not using the CRT at all are not options because some of my code is C++/CLI which is mutually exclusive with the /MT switch (and probably also with other C++ stdlibs, like STLPort, but I haven't confirmed that).

Comment: There are certain things Microsoft doesn't do because of antitrust concerns. They can't give their own components better treatment than anybody else's.

Comment: It hardly seems like an antitrust violation to support their C++ runtime transparently on their operating system. If what you say is taken just one step further, the WinSxS system itself is in danger of violating such concerns. But I can see where other compiler manufacturers would be annoyed: but I say that Microsoft should provide them a means to sign their shared runtime DLLs and allow the same elevation-free installation. Actually it gets even worse. Microsoft/Windows Update is a giant antitrust violation if you want to talk about software updates.

Comment: What part of this is frustrating to you?

Comment: Speaking as a system administrator, I don't want users to be able to install *any* system-wide software without proper authority to do so.  I don't care whose software it is.

Comment: You do have a third choice, incidentally: use the static runtime.  (And even a fourth one: don't use the runtime at all!)

Comment: @Harry: What justification could you have for not allowing new versions of the MSVC runtimes? Do you have any evidence that such an installation could cause a problem? As for using the static runtime: not an option when using .NET. As for not using the runtime at all: again, not an option with .NET (and .NET has its own runtime to install, but at least it's less frequently updated).

Comment: @David: The part where I want to use merge modules, but don't want to require administrator access for my installer.

Comment: OK then, solve that by using static runtime for MSVC. For .net, the .net runtime is a system component so you don't need to install it.

Comment: @David: Ever tried that? `Command line error D8016 : '/MT' and '/clr' command-line options are incompatible`

Comment: What language is this? C++/CLI? I am reduced to guesswork now.

Comment: Well, you know I'm using C++. And since I mentioned that the static runtime wasn't an option due to .NET in my first reply to Harry, one could deduce that I'm using C++/cLI. :) But actually I use a lot of native code and some managed wrapper code.

Comment: Using the static runtime isn't always an option. For example, my application passes STL objects accross module boundaries, which will crash and burn under a static runtime because objects will be free'd in a different heap to the one in which they are allocated.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, yeah there's nothing more frustrating than trying to support someone who installed something new that you didn't know about. "It works fine on these 1000 other systems, why not this one?"

Comment: @Mark: Really? How about getting 1000 users calling you up asking you for elevation privileges for a simple runtime dependency and then bitching about it. In any case, there is no reason that this capability can't be provided as a default which can be disabled by paranoid systems adminstrators at a local or domain level.

Comment: @MattChambers, Microsoft provides utilities for pushing out updates to 1000 systems at once without requiring any users to be involved.

Comment: Does that work for new versions of the MSVC runtime instead of updates? I.e. 2010 or 2011?

Comment: Another option would be for vcredist merge modules to support either per-user or system-wide installation where only the latter would require elevation.

Comment: @Matt: in my experience, *any* system-wide installation can cause a problem.  Incidentally, what's wrong with your first choice, putting the runtime DLLs in the application directory?  At least that way you can be sure exactly which runtime you're going to get.

Comment: Further to Mark's note, most large networks use commercial solutions such as Microsoft System Center, but for a job as simple as installing the VC runtime libraries you could just use plain old Group Policy.

Comment: @Harry: So no specific evidence against this idea? I mean, in my experience, letting the user turn the computer on and off is far more likely to cause a (hardware) failure than installing a VC runtime. Yet they're still allowed to do it! :) If every application put the runtimes in their directory, it would be a nasty bit of file duplication. I might go that route anyway if merge modules allowed it, but they don't. It's almost like Microsoft doesn't WANT you to do it that way...